# Is there a windows command-line alternative to unix's expect?

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, bash

The bash/unix/linux tool [`expect`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) can be used to automate/script console/tty programs in posix.

An example is in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780893/

I've read there are bindings for programming languages but I'm looking for an utility binary.

Is there a way to do automation like `expect` from the windows command line?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=expect%20for%20windows

Comment: @glennjackman the closest thing that gets me is activestate's tcl, which should supposedly be bundled with expect albeit I failed at first attempt to find some minimal distribution of it. Also checked http://bmrc.berkeley.edu/people/chaffee/expectnt.html which seems to be dead with last mod in 1999 according to [its archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20090328033659/http://bmrc.berkeley.edu/people/chaffee/expectnt.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can install [ActiveTcl](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads) which according to [activestate](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/expect) can install expect via `teacup install Expect`.

Usually you'd then run it via tclsh as described at [where is expect](https://community.activestate.com/faq/where-expect)

Comment: ActiveState's documentation is somewhat cryptic. After you have installed ActiveTcl and the Expect module (with `teacup install Expect`), you still won't have an `expect` executable. What you do is put your Expect code into a file starting with `package require Expect`, and then run it with `tclsh (filename)`. … P.S. ActiveState's Expect doesn't play well with `plink` (the non-GUI ssh client component of the PuTTY package).

Comment: @G-Man Yup, the fact that you don't end up with an expect binary is exactly why I posted the link to the 'where is expect' and mentioned that expect from ActiveTcl is usually invoked via tclsh.